# ¿Mi servicio window no puede acceder a una carpeta compartida?

Tags: c#, iis

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

He creado un servicio window que debe acceder a la ruta de la carpeta compartida y me sale un mensaje `access to the path xxxx is denied`

Revisando algunos paginas de ayuda dice que debo agregar permisos a los usuarios IIS_IUSRS y IUSR en otras dice usuario que inicio sesión del servicio windows pero aun así me sale el mensaje de acceso denegado, he agregado todos los usuarios anteriores pero no solucionan el problema.

Servicio Window

```
private void stLapso_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FlagTransfirio) return;

            try
            {
                FlagTransfirio = true;
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Se inicio proceso de copiado", EventLogEntryType.Information);

                string stRutaOrigen = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stRutaOrigen"].ToString();
                string stRutaDestino = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stRutaDestino"].ToString();

                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(stRutaOrigen);
                foreach (var archivo in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(stRutaDestino + archivo.Name))
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(stRutaDestino + archivo.Name, FileAttributes.Normal);
                        File.Delete(stRutaDestino + archivo.Name);
                    }

                    File.Copy(stRutaOrigen + archivo.Name, stRutaDestino + archivo.Name);
                    File.SetAttributes(stRutaDestino + archivo.Name, FileAttributes.Normal);

                    if (File.Exists(stRutaDestino + archivo.Name))
                    {
                        EventLog.WriteEntry("Se copio archivo con éxito", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EventLog.WriteEntry("No se copio el archivo con éxito", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    }
                }

                EventLog.WriteEntry("Se finalizo proceso de copiado", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }

            FlagTransfirio = false;
        }
```

Mi App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="stRutaOrigen" value="\\192.168.2.5\Usrdoc\LIQUIDACIONES_LCL_CHARTER\"/>
    <add key="stRutaDestino" value="C:\inetpub\web_15022019\Excel\"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La cuenta LocalSystem tiene amplios permisos, incluida la capacidad para escribir en el registro de eventos. Utilice esta cuenta con precaución porque podría aumentar el riesgo de ataques por parte de software malintencionado. Para otras tareas, considere la posibilidad de usar la cuenta LocalService , que actúa como un usuario sin privilegios en el equipo local y presenta credenciales anónimas a cualquier servidor remoto. En este ejemplo se produce un error si intenta usar la cuenta LocalService , ya que necesita permiso de escritura en el registro de eventos.